# handler transport error in spring boot websocket

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket

I'm implement websocket in spring-boot 1.5.8, on my local it working fine, but when I deploy to server (run in embedded server) the message notify from server is not stable, sometime client can receive message sometime not.

I check on the log and I got a message

```
2019-03-20 08:04:08.723  INFO 15506 --- [MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[2 current WS(2)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 167 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 27 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(107)-CONNECTED(107)-DISCONNECT(2)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1149], outboundChannelpool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 306], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 4, completed tasks = 4468]

(0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 27 transport error)
```

The log message show that 27 message error, I don't know how to resolve that.

Can we handle on error message event to resolve this problem?

**UPDATE**

My websocket server

```
 @Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/queue");
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/notify", "/queue", "/user");
    registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
}
```

On client side

```
function connect() {

    var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/ws/');
    var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
      stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/notify', function(notification) {
          notify(notification.body)
      });
    });

    return;
  } 

  /**
   * Display the notification message.
   */
  function notify(message) {
    $("#notifications-area").append(message + "\n");
    return;
  }
```

Comment: can u share your connection to socket code

Comment: See this....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780254/websocket-application-doesnt-work-properly-when-deployed-on-tomcat8-server

Comment: @AshwinGolani see code update in above